# Запасный или запасной

Tags: паронимы

В каком случае используют слово ЗАПАСНОЙ, а в каком - ЗАПАСНЫЙ? Почему выход - запасный, а не запасной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос

Как правильно: запасный или запасной выход?

Сочетаемость слова запасный ограничена: на равных правах со своим современным вариантом запасной оно существует только в сочетании с существительными путь, полк и выход и некоторыми другими. Равноправные варианты: запасный и запасной путь, запасный и запасной полк, запасный и запасной выход.
В сочетаниях с другими словами прилагательное запасный квалифицируется как устаревшее.

В БСЭ: запасной полив – то же, что влагозарядковый полив; см. также: запасной аэродром (Авиация: Энциклопедия. М., 1994, с. 223); запасной игрок.

Правильно

равноправные варианты – запасный выход и запасной выход.

[Словарь трудностей](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti)

Comment: Вы считаете дублирование вопроса в ответе нормальной практикой или [авторской идеей](http://rus.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15469)?

Comment: Я привожу текст полностью, так, как он представлен на грамоте. Не понимаю, что вам даст правка?

Comment: о какой "грамоте" речь? На сайтах Stack Exchange принято писать лаконично и по делу. Вопрос содержит вопрос, ответ - ответ. Какой смысл в наличии текста вопроса (*Как правильно: запасный или запасной выход?*) в Вашем ответе?

Comment: Послушайте, текст взят с Грамоты.ру. Я же привожу текст здесь с ссылкой на Грамоту.

Comment: По указанной в ответе ссылке нет текста, который Вы приводите в ответе. Вероятно она должна быть изменена на [другую](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_140). Но даже в этом случае я не вижу смысла повторять в тексте ответа вопрос, поэтому и предложил его убрать путём правки.

Answer (score 3):

1) Запасный и запасной ―  **разные выходы**.  ЗапАсный   ― это **аварийный** выход, им пользуются в крайних случаях (в автобусе это может быть окно или  люк).  ЗапаснОй  ― это **второй** выход, который просто является дополнительным к основному, главному.

2) Прилагательные **различаются по ударному и безударному окончанию**: В слове **запАсный**: ударением выделяется основа, это выход только в качестве **запАса**. В слове **запаснОй** ударением выделяется окончание прилагательного в функции определения, а именно определение **определяет/классифицирует** предмет  среди других предметов  ― в данном случае как основной (главный) или запасной (дополнительный) выход.

2) Таким образом, **расположение ударного слога подсказывает нам семантику слова.** Разумеется, ударное и безударное окончания ОЙ/ЫЙ/ИЙ складывались **исторически**, но в **современном языке** они активно используются для различения значений слов (или их оттенков), например:  домОвый и домовОй, грунтОвый и грунтовОй, джИнсовый и джинсОвый, перехОдный и переходнОй, призЫвный и призывнОй.

3) Ограниченность варианта "запасный" связана с **отсутствием необходимости в его применении  в большинстве случаев** ― например, ключ от дома всегда запасной, то есть это обычный ключ, приготовленный на случай потери или отсутствия основного.

4) **И в качестве вывода:** при различении двух вариантов уместнее было бы говорить о **терминологическом характере прилагательного "запасный"**, а не причислять его к устаревающему слову.

Answer (score 2):

Ох, непростой это вопрос, одним предложением и не ответишь.

С легкой руки Грамоты сейчас по Интернету пошло гулять утверждение, что дело только в лексической сочетаемости, но это не совсем так. 
По моим наблюдениям *запасной* и *запасный* - это слова с несколько разными значениями.
Запасный - используется для обозначения "запаса" на случай внештатной или чрезвычайной ситуации (кроме названных - запасный полк, запасный парашют и т.п); запасной - для естественной замены (запасной игрок, запасной элемент питания и т.д.). Есть случаи, когда возможны оба толкования и позволяют использовать и оба варианта прилагательного.

Но всё это - только в отношении "запасной"/"запасный" в значении "резервный".

И ещё у слова запас есть несколько значений, где возможно только запасной: 
~1. как прилагательное от запас в значении припасённый, предназначенный к использованию, т.е. значение синонимичное запасённый, припасённый, накопленный; 
~2. техническое: часть материала в изделии (швейном, например) как излишек или для подгонки "по месту";
~3. военное: граждане, находящиеся на учете для призыва в случае войны и сама система такого учета.
Здесь возможно только запасной (при этом в первом из этих значении - даже сомнительна сама возможность образования прилагательного).

Comment: Т.е. получается "запасный" - это как короткая форма "запасенный"?

Comment: Ой, не знаю. Я с таких позиций не думал... 
Да нет вроде. Запасный путь, выход - какой уж тут "запасенный". 
Но если вы о том, что "запасный" подобно причастию тяготеет к выражении состояния или результата действия, а запасной - типичное качественное прилагательное, то я пожалуй соглашусь. С некоторыми оговорками, вытекающими из моих примеров.

Comment: Да, примерно это я и имел в виду. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу Сержа:

Подобная вариантность обусловлена исторически: различие в написании окончаний именительного падежа единственного числа -ый и -ой в соответствии с отсутствием или наличием ударения на окончании (добрый, красивый, но молодой, простой) восходит к различиям между старославянской и древнерусской формами прилагательных (старославянские прилагательные имели, независимо от ударения, только окончания -ый/-ий, древнерусские — только окончания -ой/-ей, а современная норма появилась в результате смешения этих традиций) .

Сочетаемость слова запасный ограничена: на равных правах со своим современным вариантом запасной оно существует только в сочетании с существительными путь, полк, выход и некоторыми другими, тематически связанными с воинской повинностью и опасностью."Запасный" когда-то означало "резервный", от этого значения у нас осталось"выйти в запас", "уволиться в запас".

Запасный = резервный - от пасти –спасать, оберегать от опасности, а потом уже появились другие значения.

От "запасать"="сберегать" – сбережение = припас,запас; синоним копить-от "копа, куча" – делать запас.

Поскольку речь в транспорте ведется о выходе из него в случае чрезвычайной ситуации (например, при аварии), то и слово «запасный» корректно  писать именно через «ы», в других же ситуациях оно утратило то первое значение и пишется  через «о».

А какой вариант выбрать - исконный древний или современный, решайте сами.

Answer (score -1):

Запасной выход − говорит о замене, то есть используется на подмену, когда не работает основной (запасной аэродром, запасной игрок, запасной парашют...). 
Запасный выход − говорит о дополнении, то есть используется на подмогу, когда основной не справляется (запасный парашют).

Пример. Два выхода, две двери. Одна работает и через неё идет поток людей, вторая закрыта. Вторая дверь - запасной выход, в том случае, если при закрытии первого выхода, она начнет выполнять обязанности первого выхода. Вторая дверь - запасный выход, если будет работать вместе с первым выходом.
То же самое с парашютом. Если основной парашют испорчен, не действует, то будет действовать запасной. Если же при основном парашюте будет запущен ещё один парашют, то он будет - запасный. 
А вот запасной патрон останется запасным, но его не назвать - запасный. И запасной игрок будет запасным, но его никак не получится назвать - запасный.

Comment: Прежде чем давать собственный ответ, следует посмотреть ответы других участников. Если Вы видите, что Ваше объяснение уже есть в ответах (и с более аккуратной аргументацией), не стоит создавать ещё один ответ. Просто проголосуйте за свою точку зрения в уже существующем ответе.

Comment: ну-ка, покажите, кто именно так, как я ответил? все ответы неправильные

Comment: Ой, простите, действительно не вчитался: подумал, что Вы то же говорите, а на самом деле у Вас какие-то глупости. Извините за беспокойство, мне нужно было просто минус поставить и не разводить разговоры.